# selecting subsets of data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

I have a data set containing 5 rows × 1317 columns. attached you can se how the data set looks like. The header contains numbers which are wavelengths. However I only want to select the columns from a specific range of wavelength.
The wavelengths numbers which I am interested are stored in an array (c) with the size of 1 × 235.
How can I extract the desired columns according to the wavelength values stored in c?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your array `c` only has values that are also a column heading (that is, `c` doesn't have any additional values), you may be able to just make it a list and use `df[c]`, where `c` is that list.

For example, with what is shown in your current picture, you could do:

```py
l = [102,105] # I am assuming that your column headings in the df are integers, not strings
df[l]
```

This will display those two columns. If you want it in somenew dataframe, then do something like `df2 = pandas.Dataframe(df[l]) to  If` l`was 5 columns, it would show those 5 columns. And so if you can pass in your array`c`, (or make it into a list, probably by` l = list(c)`), you'll get your columns

If your array has additional values that aren't necessarily columns in your dataframe, you'll need to make a sub-list of just those columns.

```py
sub_c = list() #create a blank list that we will add to
c_list = list(c)
for column in df.columns:
    if column in c_list: sub_c.append(column)
df[sub_c]
```

This will make that sublist that only has values that are column headers, and so you want be trying to view columns that don't exist.

Keep in mind that you'll need matching data-types between your `c` array and your column headers.